# cannot find duplicate article

Tags: support, flagging, duplicates

I am trying to mark this article: [Evince 3.10 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370215/evince-3-10-on-ubuntu-12-04)

as a duplicate of this article: [How can I install the latest version of Evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310974/ubuntu-12-04-how-can-i-update-evince)

but I cannot find it in the list of duplicates. [image: screenshot of me serching for the article]

does someone have a explanation, and is someone experiencing the same on this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer**

Is in red under the text box.

Comment: alright it is time to go to bed, compleatly overlooked the text. I feel ashamed ^^

Answer (score 5):

The message says you clearly that that question has no upvoted answer. If a question has no "good" answer then the duplicated cannot be done.

I've checked both answers, and none got favorable results. I believe that evince doesn't work due "incompatibilities" with upstream. Debian was lagging the package for some reason, I haven't found the bug report again.

Also, please, **do NOT upvote answers that will not work**. The upvote means that it was useful for someone, if you are going to upvote, you either agree with the answer or the answer was tested by you and verified that it works.